# Recycler View Items are increasing when I change tab in tab layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, whatsapp

when I change from chat fragment to call fragment and then come back the items of recycler view got increased by double any solution?
please suggest anyway as I am not able to debug it. The items are increasing when I change from chat tab to call tab and then again come back to chat tab

**Chat Fragment**

```
package com.codewithdevesh.cackle.menu;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.PagerAdapter;
import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.R;
import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.adapter.ChatListAdapter;
import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.model.ChatListModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {


public ChatsFragment() {

}
private List<ChatListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView rv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
    rv = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    getChatList();
    return v;
}

private void getChatList() {
    list.add(new ChatListModel("11","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("12","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("13","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("14","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("15","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    rv.setAdapter(new ChatListAdapter(list,getContext()));
}
}
```

**ChatListAdapter**

```
package com.codewithdevesh.cackle.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.R;
import com.codewithdevesh.cackle.model.ChatListModel;
import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;

import java.util.List;

public class ChatListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatListAdapter.Holder> {

    private final List<ChatListModel> list;
    private final Context context;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChatListAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_layout,parent,false);
        return new Holder(v);
    }

    public ChatListAdapter(List<ChatListModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatListAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
        ChatListModel chatListModel = list.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(chatListModel.getUsrName());
        holder.tvDesc.setText(chatListModel.getDescription());
        holder.tvDate.setText(chatListModel.getDate());
        Glide.with(context).load(chatListModel.getUrlProfile()).into(holder.profile);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvName,tvDesc,tvDate;
        private CircularImageView profile;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tvDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
            profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);

        }
    }
//    public void  setReceiverProfileImage(Bitmap bitmap){
//         profileImage= bitmap;
//    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible case is below code snippet

```
private List<ChatListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
    rv = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    getChatList();
    return v;
}
```

`private List<ChatListModel> list` declared at class level and when you switching to another fragment `onDestroyView` getting called and when you click back `onCreateView` get called here list already holding previous data so it is getting added duplicate data.

**Possible solution**

Declare list variable local only/ check if list has already data then do not add new data just set it to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Update your *getChatList()* to this

```
private void getChatList() {
    list.clear();
    list.add(new ChatListModel("11","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("12","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("13","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("14","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    list.add(new ChatListModel("15","Devesh","good bye","15/10/2020","https://i.pinimg.com/550x/7d/1a/3f/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"));
    rv.setAdapter(new ChatListAdapter(list,getContext()));
}
```